Middlebrook Stability Criteria for Input Filter
I am trying to apply Middlebrook input filter stability criteria for Active clamp forward converter .So for finding Input filter output impedance over the frequency range is quite straight forward in simulation .
I am trying to understand how can I find the input impedance over frequency range  of Active Clamp forward converter using simulation. Is it possible to  reflect the secondary side to the primary side ?
But secondary side of the active clamp forward converter is not linear so how should reflect my secondary to primary side ,I am not able to understand .

I think it's possible in SIMPLIS, especially if you have the DVT module.  It might be difficult in other simulators.  Of course you can build it and measure Zin too.

@John D ..but would it be possible to transfer secondary side to the primary side by conventional approach? because secondary side of the Active Clamp Forward Converter is non linear.

Well of course you can't use linear stability analysis on a non-linear system without linearizing the system around a particular operating point.  So you would have to test or simulate over the expected range of operating conditions.
